# Python subsetSum Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to write a function in Python that will take the subsetSum(lst, num) and iterate through the list lst and return True if there are three values that add up to the number num. If there are not three values in list lst that add up to number num, then the function returns False. Here is what i have so far (I am just starting to learn Python so please don't be harsh!!):

```
def subsetSum(lst, n):

    ''' checks to see if 3 values in lst add up to n and returns True, otherwise false'''

    if n == 0 or n < 1:
        return False 
    elif len(lst) < 3:
        return False 

    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[0] == n:
            return True
    return False
```

Somehow i need this to iterate through the list lst and find 3 values that add up to n.

Comment: Show us your attempt so far and we will help you improve it.

Comment: Do the three numbers have to occur sequentially in the list?

Comment: @martineau No, the numbers do not have to occur sequentially in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that uses nested loops. I am only just learning the language so it probably isn't idiomatic python, but it works:

```
def subset_sum(lst, n):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)):
            for k in range(j + 1, len(lst)):
                if lst[i] + lst[j] + lst[k] == n:
                    return True
    return False
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I can't believe i didn't think of the nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Using [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and `any`:

```
>>> any(sum(e)== 30 for e in combinations(range(1,22), 3))
True
>>> any(sum(e)== 300 for e in combinations(range(1,22), 3))
False
```